# Динамические запросы в Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Каким образом можно в Spring Data JPA реализовать динамические запросы ? 
Например есть огромный фильтр и не факт что какое то поле не будет null. 
Есть идеи ?
Благодарю.

Comment: Вы можете использовать [Specifications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#specifications) для динамического построения запросов.

Comment: ознакомься с https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 2):

Можно оборачивать параметры запроса в спецификации и передавать их в запросы.

Пример запроса со спецификацией:

```
CuVotercntByCuSpecification builder = new CuVotercntByCuSpecification();
    Specification<CuVotercntByCu> specification =
        where(builder.isEqualViborrefererDate())
            .and(builder.fetch("ciuSubject"))
            .and(builder.fetch("viboryrefer"))
            .and(builder.fetch("protocolStatus"));          
List<CuVotercntByCu> allCiu = votercntByCuRepository.findAll(specification,
        Sort.by("viboryrefer.namvibor", "numokr"));
```

Пример создания спецификации:

```
public class CuVotercntByCuSpecification extends BaseSpecification<CuVotercntByCu> { }
```

Answer (score 1):

использовать `em.createNativeQuery` или `@SqlResultSetMapping`
пример тут https://javastudy.ru/spring-data-jpa/jpa-native-query/

Comment: Но это же не Spring Data, а вопрос был про него. Да и непонятно, как native query поможет в построении динамического запроса.

Comment: Сергей, тогда мой ответ плохой.

Answer (score 0):

пример native query в построении динамического запроса.

```
    case Role.CIK:
if (StringUtils.hasText(reqParam.getCiuSubject())) {
    sql += " AND cnt.vccucode_Subj =  :ciuSubject ";
    query.setParameter("ciuSubject", reqParam.getCiuSubject());
}

Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, CuVotercntByCu.class);
return query.getResultList();
```