# Как создать select из базы с помощью spring repositories с разным количеством параметров?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, repository

У меня есть фильтр для поиска - имя пользователя и две даты начала и конца. Как я могу сделать селект по этим полям используя репозитории?

```
@Service
public class ResolutionServiceDefault implements ResolutionService {
    @Autowired
    private ResolutionRepository resolutionRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Resolution> findAllFilter(String user, Date start, Date end) {
        if(user!=null)...
        if(start!=null)...
        if(end!=null)...
        //выполнить запрос по полям которые не  null
        return .....;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface ResolutionRepository extends JpaRepository<Resolution, Long> {
    List<Resolution> findAllByStatus(int status);
    List<Resolution> findAll();//String user, Date start, Date end
}
```

Comment: Связанный https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563727/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 2):

Подобные задачи решал используя интерфейс `Specification`:

```
public class ResolutionSpecs {
    public static Specification<Resolution> isActualUser(String user) {
        return new Specification<Resolution>() {
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Resolution> r, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                return cb.equal(r.get(_Resolution.user), user);
            }
        };
    }
    public static Specification<Resolution> isSomeDateAfter(Date start) {
        return new Specification<Resolution>() {
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Resolution> r, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                return cb.greater(r.get(_Resolution.someDate), start);
            }
        };
    }
    public static Specification<Resolution> isSomeDateBefore(Date end) {
        return new Specification<Resolution>() {
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Resolution> r, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                return cb.lower(r.get(_Resolution.someDate), end);
            }
        };
    }
}

@Repository
public interface ResolutionRepository extends JpaRepository<Resolution, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Resolution> {

}

@Service
public class ResolutionService {
    private final ResolutionRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ResolutionService(ResolutionRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public List<Resolution> findByUserAndSomeDateBetween(String user, Date start, Date end) {
        Specification<Resolution> sp = null;
        if (user != null) {
            sp = Specifications.where(ResolutionSpecs.isActualUser(user));
        }
        if (start != null) {
            sp = (sp == null ? Specifications.where(ResolutionSpecs.isSomeDateAfter(start)) : sp.and(ResolutionSpecs.isSomeDateAfter(start)));
        }
        if (end != null) {
            sp = (sp == null ? Specifications.where(ResolutionSpecs.isSomeDateBefore(end)) : sp.and(ResolutionSpecs.isSomeDateBefore(end)));
        }
        return repository.findAll(sp);
    }
}
```

[Документация здесь](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications).

Еще может быть вариантом использовать библиотеку для генерации SQL-запросов, например JOOQ, но боевого опыта с ней не имею. [Документация здесь](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual-single-page/#select-statement). [Пример тут](http://www.baeldung.com/jooq-with-spring).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я написал про три метода в том виде, в каком они должны быть реализованы в интерфейсе, описанном выше - чем не конкретный пример?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky понял, поправлю

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky done